# Spring Webflux TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE not streaming

Tags: java, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

I am new to reactive programming and spring webflux, i wish to try out the `MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE`, so i have the following codes:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/stream", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Menu> streamAllAvailableMenu() {
    return menuService.findAll();
}
```

What i expect for the result is, i call this API in browser (the reason of using browser is not all clients support real-time streaming), when i change my data in mongodb, it should reflect the changes immediately in my browser, like real-time streaming using web-socket technology, but in fact it didn't change anything.

Am i misunderstood this streaming mechanism, or i missed out something?

I am using full reactive stacks:

```
Spring webflux 
Netty
Spring Data MongoDB Reactive
```

Answer (score 0):

The use case you're describing does not operate over websocket (but plain HTTP with Server Sent Events). To achieve what you're trying to do, you need to [leverage the tailable cursor support in Spring Data MongoDB](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/#tailable-cursors).

For that, you need to adapt your repository definition like this:

```
public interface PersonRepository extends ReactiveMongoRepository<Person, String> {

  @Tailable
  Flux<Person> findByFirstname(String firstname);

}
```

Comment: Hi, Care to help on this one? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63908428/server-sent-event-eventstream-is-empty-and-only-shows-in-network-tab-when-flux-m - @Brian